# Can two processes on the same Azure VM connect to each other without encryption?

Tags: encryption, virtualization, azure

We're starting our cloud journey and in the first stage we'll do a lift&shift kind of migration - just replace our on-prem hosts with cloud VMs. One of the fundamental questions we need answered in order to decide on which processes we move when is the one in the subject - if I have a VM that runs two processes, can they establish a socket connection without SSL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is generally considered secure to connect via localhost without encryption.